# PHP Template engine with php code

Tags: php

Yes I know theyre isnt much information for this question but im looking for a php template engine. Every single template engine I have tried just makes my php code a comment? (Green) And i know it can be done because i have seen it before.

I just want to check if login form is set using isset

I call the class using

```
    require(JBOOT_DIR_CLASSES . 'class.template.php');
    $template = new Template(JBOOT_DIR . website_theme_dir . JBOOT_DS . website_theme . JBOOT_DS . website_theme_pages_dir . JBOOT_DS . 'welcome' . JBOOT_DS . website_theme_page_contentfile_dir);
    $template->load(JBOOT_DIR . website_theme_dir . JBOOT_DS . website_theme . JBOOT_DS . website_theme_pages_dir . JBOOT_DS . 'welcome' . JBOOT_DS . website_theme_page_contentfile_dir);
    $template->params();
    $template->removeEmpty();
    echo $template->parse();
```

And this is the class

```
<?php

class template
{
    public $template;
    public function __construct($template = null)
    {
        if (isset($template))
        {
            $this->load($template);
        }
    }
    public function params()
    {
        $this->set("username", "user x");
    }
    public function load($file)
    {
        if (isset($file) && file_exists($file))
        {
            $this->template = file_get_contents($file);
        }
    }
    public function set($var, $content)
    {
        $this->template = str_replace("{" . $var . "}", $content, $this->template);
    }
    public function publish()
    {
        /*
         * Prints out the theme to the page
         * However, before we do that, we need to remove every var
         * within {} that are not set
         */
        template::removeEmpty();
        eval("?>" . $this->template . "<?");
    }
    public function removeEmpty()
    {
        /*
         * This function would remove all empty variables from the template wrapped in     {}
         */
         $this->template = preg_replace('^{.*}^', "", $this->template);
    }
    public function parse()
    {
        /*
         * This function grabs a static document and returns the content
        */
        return $this->template;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check out [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) -> [Embedding Php into template...](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl)

Comment: do you mean that template can have php code inside it and it must be executed?

Comment: Yes. Just the shortcuts such as {myparam} and php code allowed.